# Why is there no segfault when accessing a variable that has gone out of scope using unsafe Rust?

Tags: memory, rust, unsafe, unsafe-pointers

I came across this strange phenomenon while playing with unsafe Rust. I think this code should make a segmentation fault but it does not. Am I missing something?
I tried to set a pointer to a variable with a shorter lifetime and then dereference it.

```
// function that sets a pointer to a variable with a shorter lifetime
unsafe fn what(p: &mut *const i32) {
    let a = 2;
    *p = &a;
    //let addr = *p;    // I will talk about this later
    println!("inside: {}", **p);
}

fn main() {
    let mut p: *const i32 = 0 as *const i32;
    unsafe {
        what(&mut p);

        // I thought this line would make a segfault because 'a' goes out of scope at the end of the function making the address invalid
        println!("segfault? {}", *p);

        // Even more unsettling: I can increment the address and still dereference it.
        p = ((p as usize) + 1) as *const i32;
        println!("I'm definitely missing something: {}", *p);
    }
}
```

This program outputs:

```
inside: 2
segfault? {random number around 20000. probably uninitialized memory but why?}
I'm definitely missing something: {uninitialized memory}
```

If I uncomment the line

```
let addr = *p;
```

the second row becomes

```
segfault? 2
```

Why is there no segfault? Can the compiler extend the lifetime of `a` or the address `p` points at for safety? Am I missing some basic information about pointers in Rust?

Comment: "I think this code should make a segmentation fault but it does not.", undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: Please also read [Stack Oveflow's canonical answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/279627).

Answer (score 9):

This isn't unique to Rust. See:

- [Why doesn't the following code produce a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15871423/155423)
- [Accessing an array out of bounds gives no error, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1239938/155423)
- [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/155423)

TL;DR: you have *lied* to the compiler. Your `unsafe` block does **not** uphold the requirements of safe code. This means you have created *undefined behavior* and the program is allowed to do whatever it wants. That could mean:

- it crashes (such as via a segfault)
- it runs perfectly
- it erases your hard drive
- it empties your bank account
- it generates [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)
- it [eats your laundry](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/362mx2/can_rust_eat_laundry_at_10/)
- etc.

Segfaults are **never** a guaranteed outcome. A [segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2346806/155423) occurs when you access memory that is outside of the chunk of memory your thread/process has. The memory of the stack is well inside of that chunk, so it's unlikely to trigger the case.

See also:

- [Why doesn't this Rust program crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31307454/155423)

Comment: Don't forget nasal demons

Comment: “_A segmentation fault **generally** occurs when you access memory outside the chunk that your process has_”: You can leave out the “generally” since that is the exact definition of a segfault. Other conditions can cause the program to crash, but those are not segmentation faults.

Comment: @Jmb Not true! `raise(11);` will raise a segmentation fault.